# CCNET Trunk start building because of changes set on branch

Tags: mercurial, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I am using CCNET in combination with Mercurial. I have a project that got a branch and a head. they are both configured in CCNET. The branch is running fine, it only start building when there are changes on this branch.

The trunk (called default) starts building every time modifications are checked, because it "sees" the change sets of the branch. It doesnt check them out (good think), but it keeps building every time.

How can I avoid the trunk project seeing the changesets of the branch?

> `<sourcecontrol type="hg">`
>      `<repo>http://repository/hg/hgwebdir.cgi/projectsname/</repo>`
>      `<workingDirectory>D:\projects\projectsname</workingDirectory>`
>      `<branch>default</branch>`
>      `</sourcecontrol>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you found a CCNET bug, but in case it's helpful later, if you want CCNET pulling down only a specific named branch you can use this notation for your repo URL:

```
<repo>http://repository/hg/hgwebdir.cgi/projectsname/#branchname</repo>
```

Which comes from `hg help urls`:

> An optional identifier after #
>   indicates a particular branch, tag, or
>   changeset to use from the remote
>   repository. See also 'hg help
>   revisions'.revisions'.

That assumes, of course, that CCNET is using mercurial under the covers, but that's a pretty safe bet.

Doing that will cause your CCNET to only clone down and track changesets with that branch name (which still could include multiple heads).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I looks like this is a CCNET bug, I added a changeset on the default and now it stopped building every 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

this bug is currently being worked on 
http://groups.google.com/group/ccnet-devel/t/fe3f768a346a3796

so any help with testing is appreciated :-)